# Spring Roo Generated list.html, generate all fields

Tags: html, spring, spring-roo

when Spring roo generates list.html files for an entity, spring roo is not generating table column tags for every entity field, only for the first 5 fileds.

I'm using Spring-roo RC02.

How can I configure Roo (or controller) so that every field is included in the table?

Thank you.

Comment: Spring Roo was a bit of an experiment, and as far as I know, support for it was dropped quite a while ago. Notice that the last actual release (1.3.2) was in 2014 and 2.0.0RC2 was some time in 2017. It's a dead-end. I suggest that if possible, you port your code to Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

it is hard coded in spring-roo-master\addon-web-mvc-views\src\main\java\org\springframework\roo\addon\web\mvc\views\AbstractViewGenerationService.java

Update above class and build and update bundle..